# Capture two image and display it to two UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm planning to take 2 profile picture, both are having their own separate button and image view, on same view controller.

I'm using Swift version 4 for this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var profileA: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var profileB: UIImageView!

  var profileAPicker: UIImagePickerController!
  var profileBPicker: UIImagePickerController!

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    profileAPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    profileA.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage

    profileBPicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    profileB.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
  }

  @IBAction func takeProfileA(_ sender: Any) {

    profileAPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    profileAPicker.delegate = self
    profileAPicker.sourceType = .camera

    present(profileAPicker, animated: true , completion: nil)
  }

  @IBAction func takeProfileB(_ sender: Any) {

    profileBPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    profileBPicker.delegate = self
    profileBPicker.sourceType = .camera

    present(profileBPicker, animated: true , completion: nil)
  }

}
```

It work when I take a photo for profileA, but when I'm taking a photo for profileB it stop.

Comment: could you give me project files, so i could debug it better

Comment: What error you get ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect. Your code calls `dismiss` on two implicitly unwrapped optionals without any regard to whether the properties have been set or not.

You don't need any image picker properties. Just keep track of which image view to update.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  @IBOutlet weak var profileA: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var profileB: UIImageView!

  var currentImageView: UIImageView?

  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    currentImageView?.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
  }

  @IBAction func takeProfileA(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    currentImageView = profileA

    present(picker, animated: true , completion: nil)
  }

  @IBAction func takeProfileB(_ sender: Any) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    currentImageView = profileB

    present(picker, animated: true , completion: nil)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem right...
Seems that issue can be fixed that way:

```
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    if picker == profileAPicker {
        profileA.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    }
    else if picker == profileBPicker {
        profileB.image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use `picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`